# API C# Post Message

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I try to make an post message and save the data into posgres SQL.
I get my Information in JSON then it comes to my C# Controller:

```
[HttpPost()]
public IActionResult Update([FromBody]Person person)
{
    ObjectResult result = null;
    try
    {
        if (person.Save() == 1) result = new ObjectResult(new { success = true, message = "ok", person = person }) { StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK };
        else result = new ObjectResult(new { success = false, message = "person not saved", person = person }) { StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotModified };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return result;
}
```

//Here i just want to check in the future if the method runs through
//From here it goes to my class into the save method:

```
    public int Save()
    {

        DBConnection.Connection.Open();


        string update = $"update {TABLE} set name = @name, email = @email, telefon = @telefon, where person_uid = @person_uid";

        NpgsqlCommand cmd;
            cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(update, DBConnection.Connection);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", this.Name ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", this.Email ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefon", this.Telefon ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@person_uid", this.PersonUid ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Prepare();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        DBConnection.Connection.Close();

        int result = 1;
        return result;
    }
```

From there it goes until to cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().
In my Browser -> Network i get following message:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot return null from an action method with a return type of 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.EnsureActionResultNotNull(ObjectMethodExecutor executor, IActionResult actionResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 95
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost
Referer: http://localhost/redpickle_export_21052020/person.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36
Origin: http://localhost
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
```

i know that i have an DB Connection becouse i wrote a get method to get all of the date in the same table.
I also tried to save the integer of  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); but this also doesnt work.
I always get the same error message.

OUTPUT CONSOLOE:

```
The thread 0x3620 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3c7c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'Npgsql.PostgresException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
'w3wp.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.1\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'w3wp.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.1\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'w3wp.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.1\System.Collections.Immutable.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware: Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot return null from an action method with a return type of 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.EnsureActionResultNotNull(ObjectMethodExecutor executor, IActionResult actionResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
'w3wp.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.1\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

This is my get method to get all the data in the database.
This works fine

```
    public static List<Person> GetList()
        {
            List<Person> result = new List<Person>();
            try
            {

                DBConnection.Connection.Open();

                NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand();
                command.Connection = DBConnection.Connection;
                command.CommandText = $"select {COLUMNS} from {TABLE} order by name";
                NpgsqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    result.Add(new Person()
                    {
                        PersonId = reader.GetInt32(0),
                        PersonUid = (reader.IsDBNull(1) ? (int?)null : reader.GetInt32(1)),
                        Name = (reader.IsDBNull(2) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(2)),
                        Password = (reader.IsDBNull(3) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(3)),
                        Email = (reader.IsDBNull(4) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(4)),
                        Telefon = (reader.IsDBNull(5) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(5)),
                        LocationId = (reader.IsDBNull(6) ? (int?)null : reader.GetInt32(6)),


                    });
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                DBConnection.Connection.Close();
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Can you paste complete your post method i.e. Update?

Comment: i have completet the post. Well i create a new object with result to know what happens

Comment: Why don't you debug your controller and see what exception is thrown?

Comment: Also, is  your tabled really named "TABLE"? And is `{TABLE}` correct syntax in postgres?

Comment: @Crowcoder yes it works i have already a mehtod for getting my data my debug is now also in here

Comment: OK, so back to why don't you debug it and look at the exception that is certainly being thrown but swallowed since your catch block is empty?

Comment: @Crowcoder thanks for contributing. Without your reminder i wouldnt have solved it

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error.
My SQL Statement had an `,` too much

```
string update = $"update {TABLE} set name = @name, email = @email, telefon = @telefon, where person_uid = @person_uid";
```